# error with default code for deploy firebase function

Tags: node.js, flutter, google-cloud-functions

i already set up the whole required implementation to link my flutter app with firebase function
after i done it gave me default code for deploy and testing like following

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

 // Create and deploy your first functions
 // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

 exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
   functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
   response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
 });
```

now i wanted to deply it using `firebase deploy` in terminal but i got the following error

```
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> eslint .


C:\ShowUp\functions\index.js
   4:1  error  Expected indentation of 0 spaces but found 1   indent
   5:1  error  Expected indentation of 0 spaces but found 1   indent
   7:1  error  Expected indentation of 0 spaces but found 1   indent
   8:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 3   indent
   9:1  error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 3   indent
  10:1  error  Expected indentation of 0 spaces but found 1   indent
  10:5  error  Newline required at end of file but not found  eol-last

✖ 7 problems (7 errors, 0 warnings)
  7 errors and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.

node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\Mohammed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)       
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\Mohammed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)       
    at cp.emit (C:\Users\Mohammed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at cp.emit (C:\Users\Mohammed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
  path: 'npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
  spawnargs: []
}

Node.js v18.15.0

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 1
```

the code is from default settings even . where is the error exactly ?

Comment: In firebase.json can you try changing `$RESOURCE_DIR`   to `%RESOURCE_DIR%` also check other suggestions in this github [thread](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/822)

Comment: where could i find firebase.json ?

Comment: you can find your firebase.json file at the root of your project directory

Comment: i changed it as what you said to me but with no luck . also i tried to delete it instead change it then it work . but i don't think it is good idea specially i need it for prior . no?

Comment: thanks a lot @SathiAiswarya i tried the following "functions": {
  "predeploy": [
    "npm --prefix $Env:RESOURCE_DIR run lint",
    "npm --prefix $Env:RESOURCE_DIR run build"
  ]
}, 
really thanks for ssharing that link .. without your help i will still losting my time really thanks .. it is work now perfectly

Comment: glad to hear that your issue is resolved, I have posted that as an answer. please check:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in this github [thread](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/822#issuecomment-406754186) by laurenzlong

> Completely remove the "predeploy" field from firebase.json if you
> don't actually need linting or building prior to deployment or Edit
> the predeploy script to use the right syntax for your command line
> tool will solve this issue.
>
> ```
> //firebase.json
> ```

```
"functions": {
  "predeploy": [
    "npm --prefix $Env:RESOURCE_DIR run lint",
    "npm --prefix $Env:RESOURCE_DIR run build"
  ]
},
```

Comment: please edit your anser to   
  "functions": {
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix $Env:RESOURCE_DIR run lint",
     
      ]
    },

just add another "functions": {..} syntax and remove the last line .. (it is not important if you did not remove it ) .. it work with me for two cases but important to add "functions": {..}